# How to realize communication between Cordova App and Native WatchKit Extension

Tags: cordova, ipc, watchkit, apple-watch

I would like to extend a ionic / Cordova IOS App by a WatchKit App (native written in swift). I am wondering which is the best way for communication between both. I checked the plugin: [github.com/leecrossley/cordova-plugin-apple-watch](http://github.com/leecrossley/cordova-plugin-apple-watch) which allows me to make basic communication, after changing to: MMWormholeTransitingTypeSessionMessage transition type on both sides. (Using Xcode9 and watchOS 4.0). 
Now I am asking myself if this MMWormhole is the best choice, as development stopped 2-3 years ago. Also for me is not clear if communication is possible if App is in background or even not started so far (how to check this or handle such situations?). My first tries showed that both Apps must be running and on iPhone side it's ok to be in background on WatchKit not.

How are you guys handling this?

Also saw the hint to use sockets for IPC, here I am not sure if this is possible with AppleWatch / WatchKit (have seen some answer doubting it...)
Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Finally i checked out this tiny plugin for basic communication [https://github.com/gecsbernat/cordova-plugin-watchconnectivity] (https://github.com/gecsbernat/cordova-plugin-watchconnectivity) between Cordova/Ionic and my WatchKit App.

Comment: Were you able to communication with watchOS 4.0? was is enough to use the tiny plugin and extend it functionalities? Was is a good idea to do that? Do you think it would be better to start a native IOS app?

Comment: Yes, for me this plugin (+small extensions e.g. for fileTransfers) works perfectly. Maybe (to not give you an wrong advise) my use case was simple: The Watch is the master requesting Information and triggering fileTransfers via WCSession. A native re-start was in my case no option (used for ios/android) I just extended.

Comment: I have one more question, how were you able to add the target watchos to your cordova project and build back your cordova project? Because after addind the target when I am running the command `cordova build ios` I have the following error : target specifies product type 'com.apple.watchkit2', but there is no such product type for the 'iphonesimulator' platform.

Comment: after adding the watchOS target a cordova build is not possible anymore, you have to use cordova prepare (ios) instead and run/debug via Xcode.