# Add Apple Watch app in Swift to current application in Ionic Framework on App Store

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have an app in the App Store, which is made in the Ionic 3 Framework (Angular).
I would like to make versions for Apple Watch. Unfortunately, I can not do it in the Ionic 3 Framework.

Therefore, I have a question:

I would like to make application for Apple Watch in Swift language.

Is it possible to add an application Apple Watch standalone version made in Swift Xcode, to the current application, which is in the App Store?

Comment: Were you able to do it?

Comment: I haven't tried yet :/ Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I am working on it I will let you know

Comment: I am waiting! Thanks :)

Comment: Naturo You can see my progress in my answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So far I found that it might be possible to do that, you will have to communicate to the apple watch through a Cordova plugin like those : https://github.com/leecrossley/cordova-plugin-apple-watch and https://github.com/DVenkatesh/cordova-plugin-watchconnectivity.

But it seams that they are only supporting watchOS 2.0, so I think that you can start your plugin by using one of those and change the code to make it work on watchOS 4.0.

You can see the documentation about cordova plugin here : https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/ios/plugin.html

You can look at this post : [How to realize communication between Cordova App and Native WatchKit Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46529004/how-to-realize-communication-between-cordova-app-and-native-watchkit-extension?noredirect=1#comment84435824_46529004)  this guy were able to do it.

If I have more developpement about the subject I will let you know.

UPDATE :

I have been able to establish a communication between my mobile and watch app. I have forked an existing project to make it work on ionic 3.0 (https://github.com/plbolduc/cordova-plugin-watchconnectivity)

Comment: Thank you! It's very helpful! Thanks so much! I will test :)